Combining Images Taken from Fixed Distance with Different Top and Bottom Distances
Question:
I have six thermal images taken at an angle, and I'm trying to stitch them into one seamless image without any overlapping areas. The images are named sequentially from 11.jpg to 16.jpg. The images are not taken horizontally; they are captured at an angle, which is causing difficulties in stitching them correctly.
The images can be accessed here.
Details:
Each image's top part is at an x distance and the bottom part is at a y distance and top part is far from bottom distance.
Attempted Solution:
I have attempted to use Python's OpenCV Stitcher library, but it did not work as expected.
import cv2
from cv2 import Stitcher

# List of images
images = ['11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg']

# Read images
imgs = [cv2.imread(img) for img in images]

# Initialize stitcher
stitcher = Stitcher.create()

# Perform stitching
(status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch(imgs)

# Check if successful
if status == cv2.Stitcher_OK:
    cv2.imwrite('stitched.jpg', stitched)
else:
    print('Stitching failed: ', status)

I tried second approach of cutting and cropping images which is not overlapping area to previous image part but it does not give output as expected
the output image link is here
My Goal:
To stitch all six images into one continuous image with perfect alignment and no overlapping areas.
Question:
How can I accurately stitch these angled thermal images into one seamless image using Python? Are there any specific techniques or tools that can handle images taken at an angle more effectively?
Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated!

that's not simple stitching. your camera translates along the workpiece, does not only pivot. -- further, this appears to be handheld images. you'd have an easier time if the camera moved along a fixed straight path (mechanical linear stage), with no pivoting... or doesn't translate, only pivots. -- you are imaging a plane. after removing lens distortion, you'll have to transform the view into topdown onto that plane. then you can do stitching in a plane. -- in any case, the pictures show very few features, so the usual stitching approach (feature matching) will have a very hard time.

Why were the images taken at that strange angle?  Could you not photograph them top-down, from a distance to get more of an ortho-view rather than perspective?

the image taken are solar module images in thermal.
the solar module are planted at 35 degree horizontally on ground. so the image is taken while standing in front of solar module also it is not possible to make camera parellel to solar module. so the image is captured through some angle.
